# How to get the specified button pressed in an array of buttons in iphone(not in uitableview)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uibutton

in my application i am using array of button and i need to get the specified button which was pressed in the array. how to get. 
Note: not in table view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UIViews have a integer `tag` property you can use to identify them. So in your button click handler (assuming it is the same function for all your buttons) you can get that tag and use it to differentiate between your buttons, e.g.:

```
-(void) myButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{
   switch(sender.tag){
   //Perform an action depending on button's tag
   ...
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur consideration... itz working using tag property of btn, ican get the specified btn

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
Either set up a diffrent selector/method for each button.

or

You could set the .tag property and detect on that in your method

Comment: thanks for ur consideration... itz working using tag property of btn, ican get the specified btn